# Best way to display HTML in Android with images and disables links

Tags: android, html

I have some HTML content that I want to display in an activity, but disable all links - in fact disable all ability to interact, except viewing and scrolling.

I'm not sure if the best way to do this is using a webview (how would I disable interactivity?) or a textview.

The HTML may well refer to images and the content is local - i.e. I don't need to point to a URL, I have the HTML as a local string - although this string has been obtained dynamically in another part of the app and will not be the same very time, nor will the images be local.

I am happy to have my app dynamically edit the content to remove  tags, but there may be a more elegant solution?

What's the best approach in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if the best way to do this is using a webview (how would I disable interactivity?) or a textview.

If your HTML fits within the boundaries of what is supported by `Html.fromHtml()` -- and [here's a blog post of mine](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) from a long time ago giving you an idea of what that supports -- you are welcome to use that to prepare a `Spanned` for use by `TextView`.

> I am happy to have my app dynamically edit the content to remove tags, but there may be a more elegant solution?

It depends upon the nature of the "interactivity". For simple hyperlinks, attach a `WebViewClient` that overrides `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` and eats all link clicks. However, if you have POSTed forms, or JavaScript-based "interactivity", you'll probably need to strip that stuff out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {                  
                    return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, although I need to return true, not false.